# docker-compose volumes_from equivalent with version 3

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create an Nginx/PHP FPM setup with docker compose and am having issues with the version 3 volumes syntax/changes.

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7-fpm
VOLUME /var/www/html
```

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  php:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
  web:
    image: nginx
    links:
      - php
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    volumes:
      - php:/var/www/html
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
volumes:
  php:
```

When I add an `index.php` file into `./html`, I can view that by going to http://localhost:8888, but any static files (like CSS) return a 404 because Nginx cannot find those in its container (`/var/www/html` is empty on the nginx container). With version 3 docker compose files do not have `volumes_from` anymore, which is basically what I'm trying to replicate.

How can I get this to work with version 3?

Answer (score 43):

For using "Named volumes" for sharing files between containers you need to define

1) `volumes:` section on the top level of yml file and define volume name

```
volumes:
  php:
```

2) define `volume` section on first container like you did (Where share will mount)

```
web:
    volumes:
      - php:/var/www/html #<container_name>:<mount_point>
```

3) define `volume` section on second container (Share will mount from)

```
php:
  volumes:
    - php:/var/www/html
```

4) *(optionally)* If you need to store volume data on the host machine you can use [local-persist](https://github.com/CWSpear/local-persist) docker plugin. You can specify docker volume driver and path where you data will be stored.

```
volumes:
  php:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /path/on/host/machine/
```

**In your case** you forgot define volume name for `php` container. Just replace

```
  php:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
```

to

```
  php:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - php:/var/www/html
```

and use Local Persist Docker Plugin

Comment: How does the `.html/` files get loaded into `/var/www/html` with this setup?

Comment: Sorry, i missed that you need volume external mounting. You can use [local-persist](https://github.com/CWSpear/local-persist) docker plugin to achieve the same results.I will update the answer.

Comment: So whats the benefit of named volumes if you want to mount local folder into the container? Or in other words: does this eval to "there is no real equivalent for `volumes_from` in v3"? Because in v2 i could use the volumes_from as a wrapper for a bunch of mounts, so i define the mounts once, then "include" on the same mounts on other services via `volumes_from`. If i understand your answer correctly, in v3 i will have to define each mount separately on each service, right?

Comment: Please note that you have to give it the **full path** for `local-persist` to work properly. It doesn't mount relative paths.

Comment: A note that this works if the files in the container image at `/var/www/html` are only needed for initialization. After the volume is created, it will not be updated by newer images of the `php` container.

Comment: having this "empty" volume at the top first seemed counter-intuitive to me, however it worked. I could replace the "volumes_from" declaration and upgrade to  docker-compose version 3.5. Thanks! :)