# How can I use a directory from another container in docker-compose v3?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I created a Docker image `development-certificates` which contains a volume directory with several self-signed certificates for our development environment.

I now want to use these certificates in another container (such as the `nginx` container). How can you do this in docker-compose v3? In docker-compose v2, there is the `volumes_from` directive, but that is not possible anymore in v3.

Comment: possible duplicate from [docker-compose volumes_from equivalent with version 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42232051/docker-compose-volumes-from-equivalent-with-version-3)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create named volumes instead:

```
version '3'

services:
    certs:
      image: development-certificates
      volumes: 
        - certificates:<path-to-certs>
    nginx:
      image: nginx
      volumes: 
        - certificates:<path-to-certs>    
volumes:
    - certificates
```

If the `development-certificates` container has been created sparately, just remove the `certs` service above and get the volume name previously
created and add it to the volumes section:

docker volume ls    // find the name of the certs vol

```
version '3'

services:
    nginx:
      image: nginx
      volumes: 
        - certificates:<path-to-certs>    
volumes:
   certificates:
      external:
        name: actual-name-of-volume
```